# Input password into SSH without typing

Tags: ssh

At work, I access both a remote system via SSH and some web interfaces that login through LDAP. I use 1password to manage my passwords, but I can't seem to find a simple way to input the password from the password manager to SSH. I saw `sshpass` but it can show the password in `ps`, which is really bad security, and also doesn't work in my case. Is there any way to input a password from an external program or script through SSH directly, or are there facilities within SSH that I can leverage and keep the passwords in sync? Such as keeping a key file that I unlock for SSH that has the same password, which is updated whenever I update the password. Note I can't directly use keys to log into the system because it's not built to support it.

Edit: One commenter pointed out that `sshpass` will show the password in `ps`, which is a no-go. I also can't directly alias `ssh` to something like `sshpass ... ssh` because I do still log into systems that use keys.

Edit 2: I got confirmation that a password manager is okay, and I attempted to use `sshpass` with a file descriptor to log into the server but it doesn't seem to work -- instead of giving me a prompt to enter my RSA token, I just get nothing, which makes me think it doesn't run through the same code and won't accept `sshpass`.

Comment: Make an alias/shell function/script with another name specifically for the one host.

Comment: No, unfortunately, as far as I know. It's a government system and I have to log in with password and RSA token.

Comment: I suppose informing them that using keys instead of passing the password over the connection is safer and that passwords are an inherent security risk isn't an option, right?

Comment: I doubt it... If it was a company I could talk to an IT guy, but it's likely a mandatory thing within the government to use RSA token and password.

Comment: Server side passwords give the server an option to require sufficient password strength and to limit brute-forcing. Keys don't: the user might even leave the key unencrypted. Passwords can of course be eavesdropped, but so can the passphrase protecting the key. (And any software keylogger would likely have enough access to also copy the key file.) Keys _are_ nice, but they require a certain type of trust in the user, and their device, something that a security policy is not likely to have. ;) The next question that comes to mind is: does the policy allow storing the password on a computer?

Comment: @ilkkachu The user might also be storing the password unencrypted, so that is not really a sensible comparison. And brute forcing an SSH key is practically impossible, so servers don't have to worry about that. But they sure can, just as much as they can with passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going another route, due to `sshpass` not working with my work's setup and I did not want to use another command to login. I used a combination of `expect`, the ssh config parameter `LocalCommand`, and a Node script to get my password. See [Is it possible to exit from SSH in LocalCommand?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302240/is-it-possible-to-exit-from-ssh-in-localcommand) as well.

Essentially my solution is this:

1. Set up a ssh host, e.g. `Host work` with a `HostName` that points to my machine, e.g. `HostName localhost`
2. Add the `PermitLocalCommand yes` and `LocalComamnd <path to my expect script>; kill $PPID` to the `Host` config
3. Use the expect script to:

   1. run my Node script, which will get my password and save it into a variable
   2. Use that saved password during the expectation and then interact (see below)
4. When the SSH session finishes, the `LocalCommand` will run the `kill $PPID`, which will return me back to my original terminal session.

Here is my example `expect` script:

```
set password [exec node <script>]
spawn -noecho ssh <work_host>
expect "Password"
send "${password}\n"
interact
```

Answer (score 8):

`sshpass` does not have to show the password in the ps. It might read it an environment variable:

```
SSHPASS=12345 sshpass -e ssh user@host
```

or from a file:

```
sshpass -f /path/to/password_file ssh user@host
```

Comment: Using `-d<fd>` should be safer - however, it's tricky to use from bash without either using `mkfifo` (which gives at least a theoretical attack window) or sending the password on `stdin` (which would break your interactive ssh shell). Something like perl, or python (or C) can probably do it more cleanly.

Comment: Yes, this is not a secure solution, but still better than writing it on command line. Using separate FD is probably the best solution from all the wrong we are proposing here. But the passwords have their purpose, so the warning about the password policy still applies.

Comment: I tried `sshpass` but it doesn't seem to work... I'm thinking that the configuration on the server isn't set up like a normal SSH system (it does require an RSA token). Are there other solutions, such as a key file that contains my password that I can unlock and that SSH can use?

Comment: `ps` can list environment variables (environment variables and command line arguments are just two parallel path of input to an executable).

Answer (score 5):

My sshpass has an option `-f` to read from a file. So with bash process substitution you can do

```
sshpass -f <(myscript_call_1password) ssh host
```

Answer (score -3):

Answering the original question about automation and keystroke elimination:

> I saw `sshpass` but it requires typing the `sshpass` command before running `ssh`, which is somewhat inconvenient.

Based on your comment:

> I have a script that communicates with the 1password database, so I'm looking to integrate the script and SSH.

Define an alias (for example in bash):

```
alias ssh='sshpass -p$(<your_script>) ssh'
```

And use it as a regular `ssh` call.

Comment: Won't this still wind up leave the password visible in `ps` ?

Comment: @Shadur That's not in the question.

Comment: It *should* be.

Comment: Please comment under the question then.

Comment: Another thing is that I can't just alias SSH in this way because there are other systems where I don't type in a password and use keys. I'll update OP.

Comment: It's not "typing a few characters is inconvenient", it's that I have to open my password manager separately, copy the password, and then paste it into the terminal. I also didn't realize that `sshpass` puts the password in `ps`, which is not feasible, so `sshpass` does not work.

Comment: Quote: "*I saw sshpass but it requires typing the sshpass command before running ssh*". Regarding `ps` if you are concerned with the security of your workstation, you shouldn't be using it, and especially you shouldn't be running 1password accessible through a script on it.

Comment: If you don't agree with my question or my reasoning then feel free to delete your answer and/or down vote my question.

Comment: No, I prefer to point out inconsistencies in your comments by quoting relevant parts.

Comment: Regardless of any misconceptions the OP might have had when writing the question, you shouldn't be recommending insecure solutions in your answers.

Comment: @Ajedi32 There were no misconceptions, the original question was about typing a few characters less. Insecure against what threat? Someone having code monitoring what happens on your workstation?

Comment: @techraf The misconception the OP had was "I also didn't realize that sshpass puts the password in ps". And yes, on a shared workstation it'd certainly be a bad idea to expose your password to every user on the system, and even on a single-user workstation it'd still be a bad idea to expose your password to unprivileged processes.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Yes. I fully agree. However this as much theoretical discussion as if copying and pasting password through a clipboard is safe or not. If you have malware monitoring process list, you have bigger problems to deal with. And Mac workstations are shared so rarely, that I would expect OP to mention it in the first sentence.