# Is it possible to exit from SSH in LocalCommand?

Tags: ssh

I know it's not the intended use case of LocalCommand with SSH, but if I wanted to run a command and then exit from the SSH session directly using LocalCommand, is it possible?

E.g.:

```
LocalCommand <some command>; exit
```

I tried the above but it doesn't seem to work and still spawns the shell.

Comment: Add a dedicated public key to `authorized_keys`, and add `command=...` to it.  See `man sshd | less +/command=` for details.  Then to run the command on the server you'd just `ssh` with the corresponding private key.

Comment: I don't see the point of the question: why are you calling ssh if you don't want to run a command on the remote machine? Just to test that you can log in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local command is a child of the ssh client process. If you want to close the session, you can kill the client, i.e. kill the parent of the local command.

```
LocalCommand kill $PPID
```

Then SSH will connect to the remote host and, as soon as the authentication has been performed, but before running a remote command, the client will be killed.

I don't see the point. Why not run a no-op remote command (`ssh ''` or `ssh :`), which will exit immediately after logging in?

Comment: The purpose was to run a LocalCommand interactive script that tunneled into another system after some interaction, in this case with a password manager, and once that session is closed, I wanted to close the SSH session as I'm not using that system for anything other than tunneling at this point.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**

```
ssh foo@bar.com  'cd foo/bar && rm *.foobar'
```

This will still print the output in the stdout but exit by default after executing the command.

**Solution 2 :**

Solution specific to your use-case :
Based on  the comment where you had mentioned, you will use ssh only for this ssh command,

You could edit the file called, **`/etc/profile`**

At the last line, just make all the commands, you want to execute, and then type exit

Ex :

```
ls / > /tmp/output
exit
```

This will run the command and exit the session

and you could just call it using, `ssh user@host` , nothing else.

PS : This will only run the command and exit, remember, if you wanted to ssh into the system for anything, this would not let you, **unless you remove the exit in the last line.**

Comment: I want to do it specifically in LocalCommand so I can simply run `ssh host_name`

Comment: Do you ssh into the system, for anything else ?

Comment: No, I'm just going to ssh into this system to run the command and then exit the session.

Comment: I have added a solution 2, to the answer, check it out.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I am specifically looking for something I can run in LocalCommand, in case I do other kinds of work on the system (so that I can have multiple Hosts in my config pointing to the same system without creating a new user), which another answer provided.