# scp or ssh with password

Tags: ssh, solaris, password, scp

I want to send a file from one server to another server using a script. I have the password but how can I pass the password to the script. I am using Solaris 5.10

Comment: Check out `sshpass`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input password into SSH without typing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298050/input-password-into-ssh-without-typing)

Answer (score 4):

Using passwords in scripts is not recommended. Instead, you can use ssh keys to allow login without a password.

On the machine running the script, run `ssh-keygen` to generate a keyfile. You can hit enter for all questions, default settings will work fine. Once you have a keyfile, you can copy it to the other server with `ssh-copy-id other.server`. This will install the file correctly so you can log in. `ssh-copy-id` will ask for a password. If you try to `ssh` or `scp` to the other server now, it should no longer require a password.

If you still feel like putting a password in your script is the only option (which it isn't, and you shouldn't), you could write an `expect` script to enter the password when `ssh` or `scp` prompts for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expect script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set ip [lindex $argv 0]
set user [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
#Source File Path
set source [lindex $argv 3]
#Destination Path
set dest [lindex $argv 4]

spawn bash -c "scp $source $user@$ip:$dest"
expect "password:"
send "$password\r"
interact
```